# Specify files with xlsx extension in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

How do I set up my if statement to only take xlsx files from the specified folder?

Hi I am running a macro that takes excel files out of multiple folders and sub folders and then compiles these into one excel file. It decides which file to pull as only 1 file can be pulled from a location called hoover test.

The relevant part of the macro is here and I am looking to change the loop to recognise only ".xlsx" files:

```
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
Dim SubFolder As Folder
Dim i As Integer
Dim CopyR As Range


For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder


Next


If Folder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
    If Folder.Files.Count = 1 Then
          Else: MsgBox "2+ files: " & Folder.Path
    End If
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        Hoover File
    Next

Else
End If



End Sub
```

This works well for checking for two files in a folder but I wish to only take the xlsx file from that folder.

The full macro is here if needed:

```
'Option Explicit
Public wbm As Workbook
Public wbk As Workbook
Public File As File

Sub CM()

Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
HostFolder = "C:\Review Pack\Hoover Test"
Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wbm = ThisWorkbook
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
For Each sht In wbm.Worksheets
    sht.Cells.Replace what:="" & Chr(10) & "", Replacement:=" ",     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False,     ReplaceFormat:=False
Next sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'LightOff
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
Dim SubFolder As Folder
Dim i As Integer
Dim CopyR As Range


For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder


Next


If Folder.SubFolders.Count = 0 Then
    If Folder.Files.Count = 1 Then
          Else: MsgBox "2+ files: " & Folder.Path
    End If
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        Hoover File
    Next

Else
End If



End Sub

Sub Hoover(File)
Dim i As Integer
Dim LineNo As Integer
Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(File.Path, , False)
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False


If wbk.MultiUserEditing Then
    wbk.ExclusiveAccess
End If
For i = 2 To 11

    If Sheets(i).FilterMode Then
        wbk.Sheets(i).Unprotect "x"
        Sheets(i).Cells.AutoFilter
    End If

    LineNo = wbm.Sheets(i).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wbm.Sheets(i).Range("A" & LineNo & ":" & "AB" & LineNo + 990).Value =    wbk.Sheets(i).Range("A10:AB1000").Value
Next i
     wbk.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: How do I set up my If statement to only take xlsx files from the specified folder

Comment: You should update your question to be more explicit :)

Comment: Thanks I changed it there

Comment: where exactly would you like to do it?

Comment: Should just have to right the filename by 4: If right(File.name, 4) = "xlsx" then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file system object ready and waiting. Use:

```
FileSystem.GetExtensionName(file) = "xlsx"
```

or

```
Right$(file.Path, Len(file.Path) - InStrRev(file.Path, "."))
```

Comment: @QHarr: `file.extension` does not work for me (*"...does not support this property"*), tried with Excel 2010 and 2016, both with late and early binding. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Try FileSystem.GetExtensionName instead. And I will have a look at the first.

Comment: @myles collier: Be aware that a file can have the exension written in upper case.

Comment: @FunThomas Think I may have mixed up vbScript on first. Well spotted. Edited

Answer (score 0):

change your loop over the files to

```
For Each File In Folder.Files
    If LCase(Right(File.Name, 5)) = ".xlsx" Then
        Hoover File
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I get lost with your conditional instructions in the DoFolder script, but I guess you want to perform some action only if the subfolder contains at least 2 .xlsx files. I think you could iterate through all files in subfolders and just check if they have string ".xlsx" or ".xls" in their name. The latter option will count also .xlsm and .xlsb.

You may use this function:

```
Function CountXLS(folder) As Long
    Dim f As Object
    Dim cnt As Long

    For Each f In folder.Files
        If InStr(f.Name, ".xls") Then cnt = cnt + 1
        'If InStr(f.Name, ".xlsx") Then cnt = cnt + 1 'more precise variant
    Next f

    CountXLS = cnt

End Function
```